# import errors with Enthought Canopy

Tags: enthought

I recently undated to the latest version of Enthought Canopy (Python 2.7x). I have some python code that was working a month ago with an older version of Enthought Canopy. Now I am getting error messages related to tests and checking when I use "import". The exact same code works fine with Anaconda Spyder, so nothing has changed in my code. I am sure something was changed in the newer version of Canopy but the Enthought folks won't talk to me (I'm a free academic user). I am a "number cruncher" and not a Python expert at all. I would appreciate any help you can give me. I am using a Macbook Pro with OS X 10.8.5. I am using Canopy version 1.4.1 (64 bit).

Here is the import part of the code (same error with any "import" command):
`import numba`

Here are the error messages:

```
Welcome to Canopy's interactive data-analysis environment!
 with pylab-backend set to: inline
Type '?' for more information.

In [1]: %run "/Users/kgilbert/Desktop/python2.7Nov2013/FourierPE/Fourier_PE _ORIGINAL2 copy.py"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnsupportedOperation                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    202             else:
    203                 filename = fname
--> 204             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/Users/kgilbert/Desktop/python2.7Nov2013/FourierPE/Fourier_PE _ORIGINAL2 copy.py in <module>()
     36 '''
     37 
---> 38 import numba
     39 import FiniteDifferencePE_modules
     40 import FourierPE_modules

/Users/kgilbert/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/__init__.py in <module>()
      4 from __future__ import print_function, division, absolute_import
      5 import re
----> 6 from . import testing, decorators
      7 from ._version import get_versions
      8 from . import special, types, config

/Users/kgilbert/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/testing.py in <module>()
      5 import numba.unittest_support as unittest
      6 
----> 7 from numba.tests import NumbaTestProgram
      8 from numba.utils import StringIO
      9 

/Users/kgilbert/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/tests/__init__.py in <module>()
    175     pass
    176 else:
--> 177     faulthandler.enable()

/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/zmq/iostream.pyc in fileno(self)
    174 
    175     def fileno(self):
--> 176         raise UnsupportedOperation("IOStream has no fileno.")
    177 
    178     def write(self, string):

UnsupportedOperation: IOStream has no file no.
```

NEW OUTPUT BELOW

### Canopy now has numba version 0.14.0-1 Here are the error messages:    %run "/Users/kgilbert/Desktop/python2.7Nov2013/FourierPE/Fourier_PE _ORIGINAL2 copy.py"

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    202             else:
    203                 filename = fname
--> 204             **builtin**.execfile(filename, *where)

/Users/kgilbert/Desktop/python2.7Nov2013/FourierPE/Fourier_PE _ORIGINAL2 copy.py in ()
     36 '''
     37 
---> 38 import numba
     39 import FiniteDifferencePE_modules
     40 import FourierPE_modules

/Users/kgilbert/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/**init**.py in ()
      4 from **future** import print_function, division, absolute_import
      5 import re
----> 6 from . import testing, decorators
      7 from ._version import get_versions
      8 from . import special, types, config

/Users/kgilbert/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/testing.py in ()
      3 import contextlib
      4 
----> 5 import numba.unittest_support as unittest
      6 
      7 from numba.tests import NumbaTestProgram

### AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'unittest_support'

QUESTION: WHAT HAPPENS WHEN YOU IMPORT NUMBA FROM IPYTHON
ANSWER: I GET THE FIRST ERROR MESSAGE ABOVE (GIVEN HERE BELOW)
Welcome to Canopy's interactive data-analysis environment!
 with pylab-backend set to: inline
Type '?' for more information.

### In [1]: import numba

UnsupportedOperation                      Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 import numba

/Users/kgilbert/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/**init**.py in ()
      4 from **future** import print_function, division, absolute_import
      5 import re
----> 6 from . import testing, decorators
      7 from ._version import get_versions
      8 from . import special, types, config

/Users/kgilbert/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/testing.py in ()
      5 import numba.unittest_support as unittest
      6 
----> 7 from numba.tests import NumbaTestProgram
      8 from numba.utils import StringIO
      9

/Users/kgilbert/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/tests/**init**.py in ()
    175     pass
    176 else:
--> 177     faulthandler.enable()

/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/zmq/iostream.pyc in fileno(self)
    174 
    175     def fileno(self):
--> 176         raise UnsupportedOperation("IOStream has no fileno.")
    177 
    178     def write(self, string):

UnsupportedOperation: IOStream has no fileno.

In [2]:

Comment: What versions of numba are you using here and with Spyder? (And what version of Python with Spyder?)

Comment: with enthought canopy numba = 0.13.4-1 and python = 2.7.3-1        with anaconda spyder numba = 0.14.0  and python = 2.7.8

Comment: correction my enthought canopy is using python 2.7.6 NOT 2.7.3-1

Comment: First step, then, update numba to 0.14.0 in Canopy, either in the package manager or with `enpkg numba` in a Canopy Terminal (opened from Canopy Tools menu).

Comment: I updateD Numba to version 0.14.0-1 and get a different error message. The results start at NEW OUTPUT BELOW

Comment: What happens if you open a Canopy Command Prompt window (from the Start Menu or from the Canopy Tools menu), start ipython, and type "import numba"?

Comment: When I do "import numba" in ipython, I get the first error message shown above. If I do it a second time, I get the second error message.

Comment: Here is an observation: When I put in numba? in Spyder, I get some information. When I put in numba? in Canopy I get: Object `numba` not found. Looks like Canopy cannot find numba even though it is included in the installed packages. Any suggestions?

Comment: Code with numba is working now. I have no idea why. Here's what I did: After using "import numba" twice (in the editor) and getting two different error messages, I tried ?numba and got some info. That is, I did not get "Object not found" as I had previously. Using import numba again I did not get an error message. Tried the code with numba and it ran fine. Apparently, Canopy had a problem finding numba previously. Still a mystery. Hope my code continues to work. If you have some insight on this issue, please let me know.

Comment: Great! Had you rebooted, logged out/in, or applied any system updates in the meantime?

Comment: Jonathan, no. In fact, whenever I quit Canopy, I have to redo the ritual that lets Canopy find numba. It looks like there is some kind of path problem that the ritual fixes. Enthought might consider trying to reproduce the problem and and fix it. Incidentally, I appreciate your attention and help. I am impressed that you are working over the weekend (without pay I assume). Speaks well for you and Enthought

Comment: Correction. I tried the code twice just now without first doing the ritual and the code worked fine. Hopefully, whatever was the problem is now fixed permanently (yeah!).

Comment: "Enthought might consider trying to reproduce the problem and and fix it". Unfortunately, unless a problem is either (a) reproducible or (b) present on enough systems to discern a pattern, it would be too labor-intensive to try to track down to be worth it, in comparison to the large number of low-hanging fruits that could be picked (known improvements at known cost). Thanks though for your diligent reporting, which could be very useful if similar problems emerge for others (or, hope not) for you again.

Comment: Jonathan, the code is working but I am getting the following warning every time:        /Users/kgilbert/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/tests/__init__.py:393: UserWarning: Failed to enable faulthandler due to:
IOStream has no fileno.
  warnings.warn(msg.format(err=e))

Comment: This happens in which of the following environments? (a) inside the Canopy GUI appliction; (b) From an ipython session started in a Canopy Command prompt; (c) From an `ipython qtconsole` session started in a Canopy Command prompt.

Comment: Jonathan, it is inside the Canopy GUI application. I start Canopy and open the file in question. Then I click the green triangle to run the code. It runs, but with the warning cited above.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: Of the other environments that I listed above, in which ones does this code run successfully, and in which ones does it not?